# How to use git (git config --global)?

Tags: git, configuration

The [Pragmatic Guide to GIT](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/pg_git/pragmatic-guide-to-git) has the following "Git uses both to calculate the commit ID—a SHA-111 hash—that identifies each commit." in page 21.

And in page 22, I can use the following command to 'Configure Git to know who you are'.

```
git config --global smcho "Your Name"
```

When I ran it, I got the following error message.

```
error: key does not contain a section: smcho
```

What's wrong with this? I guess it has something to do with SHA-111 hash, but I don't know how to get it to be used with git.

### ADDED

I thought user.name is to be replaced my name, not a section/parameter structured name. After changing that it works OK.

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

Comment: I had the same wrong assumption about user.name. Looks just like placeholder text. That's kind of the real "answer" here.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Not sure where "smcho" comes from, but the setting to set your name is `user.name`:

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

You can set your e-mail address too:

```
git config --global user.email "name@domain.example"
```

I guess the reason it complains about the lack of a section is that the name of the parameter to set probably needs to be in two parts: `section.parameter_name` (You can see the sections names within `[]` if you look in the configuration file, for example in `.git/config`).

(None of this is specific to OSX as far as I'm aware.)

Comment: You can also set the user.name and user.email fields on a per-repository basis. If you have the defaults set, just change into the directory with the .git folder and run the commands again without the --global flag. Came in useful for me when I started using GitHub, so I could hide my 'real' or work email address.

Comment: @ConnorG, THANKS that is exactly what I was about to ask, and exactly for the same reason!

Answer (score 9):

to edit the whole config file

```
git config --global --edit
```

Answer (score 8):

A simple answer to this question/problem is that do not replace "user.name" with your actual git username leave the user.name as it is
the command needs to be:

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name here only"
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is because you have this word (smcho) at the beginning of your .gitconfig file at home directory.

Bit late, but could be useful to somebody.