# Saving git username/password in tortoisegit

Tags: git, credentials, tortoisegit

I am unable to save credentials using TortoiseGit

These are the settings I have

**In Tortoise Blame->Settings->Git**

```
Config Source: Global
Name: xx xx
Email:x@x.com
```

**In Tortoise Blame->Settings->Git->Credentials**

```
Credential Helper: Advanced
Config Type: Global  
Helper: wincred  
Username:mydomain\myuname
```

However, even after doing this when I go to Windows explorer -> git clone ...
and fill up remote repository details, I get the login name dialog box.

How do I save loginname & password, so that I am not asked for it?

UPDATE: From the command line, this is what git global config shows

```
c:\>git config --global -l
user.name=xx xx
user.email=x@x.com
credential.helper=wincred
credential.username=mydomain\myumae
core.autocrlf=false
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use git (git config --global)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580802/how-to-use-git-git-config-global)

Comment: @msw - I have updated my question with output of git config --global. My question is not a duplicate. Setting it in the tortoise UI does the same thing as git config --global

Comment: Did you entered your login/password at least once from Tortoise?

Comment: @VonC I used the Git Clone from explorer menu. Entered username/password. And then deleted the repo. And redid the Git Clone - I was asked for username/password again.

Comment: OK, then something is amiss indeed. What version of Tortoise are you using?

Comment: @VonC version 1.8.16

Comment: And that comes with what version of git?

Comment: @VonC - it did not come with git. I had to install git separately - git version 2.7.0.windows.1

Comment: And if you do a git clone through command line, do you also get the prompt for username/password (do it twice to be sure)